# selecteditem range

Tags: range, selecteditem

I have two cmboboxes that displays all the cases no a coordinator has. Note that the case no is not sequential meaning 1 case can be no.001 the next can be 010, 014, 019 and so on..

ex. coordinator A has 4 cases with nos. 1,3,5,8,25.(this will be in a list form and will be the itemsource of both comboboxes from and to)

The user has to choose the case(s) she wants to print.
cboFrom.selectedItem  = 3
cboFrom.selectedItem  = 8
By choosing 3 and 8, program will have to generate mail merge case no. 3, 5 and 8.

Question is how do I get the case(s) no. in between the selected from and to items?
I can't use for loop since it is not sequestial. What is the best way? Sorry I didn't come up to a solution coz nothing is working and I am clueless. I only know if it is squestial or in date range.

thanks for the help.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I used LINq skip and take. I haven't fully tested it but so far it is working the way I want. it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fromCase = Convert.ToInt32(cboCaseFrom.SelectedItem.ToString());
                int toCase = Convert.ToInt32(cboCaseTo.SelectedItem.ToString()); 
var selectedCases = _caseList.Where(CaseNo => Convert.ToInt32(CaseNo) >= fromCase && Convert.ToInt32(CaseNo) <= toCase);
```